# How to keep web traffic private with a satellite intenet connection

Tags: privacy, web-browser, satellite

I use satellite internet and I would like to have some a little more privacy when using the internet.

TCP spoofing appears to be an issue among other things and the people from a well known VPN service tell me its a no-go. I wonder if could use a VPS as a secure proxy?

I would like the solution to work on a router level, my speed is 10Mb/s and there is no streaming/gaming - light use. A degree of 'privacy' would be good - I don't think 'anonymity' exists for my pockets. How would I go about it?

Comment: Say more about "TCP spoofing appears to be an issue among other things and the people from a v.well known vpn service tell me its a no go". A VPN would be the obvious solution (assuming you trust the VPN provider more than you trust the satellite provider), so if there's some reason why that wouldn't work, please be very clear and detailed about it. You can use Tor or light browsing.

Answer (score 2):

**The correct way is a VPN**.

Since satellite communication is already relatively slow adding a VPN in the middle will just slow it down. Only if you really don't trust your provider go ahead and use a VPN.

> I wonder if could use a VPS as a secure proxy?

You can. But you have to make sure (and trust yourself) that you are able to provide the correct security measures you are looking for.

Comment: With satellite connections it's not just the service provider you need to trust. Satellite connections are sending data over the air. You can trivially eavesdrop on the downstream by standing a few meters away with a satellite dish pointing in the same direction as that of the user. Eavesdropping on the upstream is a bit harder, but not impossible either (wit a drone, for example).

Comment: Well it really depends what provider. Some satellite provider encrypt all the traffic by default and provide you with a decryption key (in form of a smart card) which you then insert into your receiver.

Comment: @BubbleHacker that's assuming the crypto is secure, which may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time - I think I got the wrong end of the stick when I looked into this and ended up believing that a vpn was simply not possible - it turns out it is but just may be slow.